# What does HEAD point to?

Tags: git, branch

I want to compare my local `master` branch with the remote `origin/master` branch. I know how to do `git pull --rebase; git diff origin/master` from my local `master` branch to detect the line-by-line differences in the code. But, I want to compare the commit histories, i.e., show `git log` and `git log origin/master` side-by-side. I tried `git show-branch -a` but got:

```
* [master] change content background-color to blue
 ! [origin/HEAD] add favicon
  ! [origin/master] add favicon
---
*   [master] change content background-color to blue
*++ [origin/HEAD] add favicon
```

1. Is there a better way?
2. Also, what does `HEAD` point to, the checked-out commit?

Comment: The question's title should really be changed. You're really asking about diffing things, and the accepted answer is about diffing things. Please rename the question and remove the #2. so that it stops showing up as a bad search result for the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
git log master..origin/master
```

to list the commits that are "between" `master` and `origin/master`.

`HEAD` points to the checked out commit.

Both the dot-dot syntax and HEAD are documented at [gitrevisions(7)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link. It says: "HEAD names the commit your changes in the working tree is based on" A.K.A the checked-out commit. :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Is there a better way...

   1. to detect the line-by-line differences in the code?

      `git diff origin/master..master`
   2. to compare the commit histories?

      `git log origin/master..master`
2. Also, what does HEAD point to, the checked-out commit?

   HEAD points to the "tip" of the current "branch".

Answer (score 0):

This gives me a reasonably good way to look at differences while having commits from both branches visible

```
git-forest --date-order $(git merge-base master origin/master) master origin/master
```

(Alternatively, replace by `gitk` or `git log --oneline --graph`..)

Comment: Hadn't heard of git-forest before; there's some [information on the git wiki](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Interfaces,_frontends,_and_tools#git-forest). For most cases, as you suggest, the builtin tools are probably sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `git fetch` not `git pull`. `git pull` would try to merge the branch.  You are now in a conflict, use `git merge --abort` to abort it.